# How can I create a shell script that will take me to a folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a specific workspace that I must navigate to that is annoyingly long. like/really/damn/annoyingly/long/and/it/takes/a/while/to/type. I wanted to write a shell script that would just `cd` me into it, but of course, that won't work. Is there another way to make it so I can just cd into this directory without the hassle of typing it out?

Don't tell me copy and paste.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to re-create the functionality of Windows 10, "command prompt here", from a pop-up menu? This is an already build-in feature in Gnome when you browse using Files. Highlight a folder, right click and choose Open in Terminal.

Comment: Read `man bash`, see `CDPATH`

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a shell script to change directory, because the script runs in a different process and that child process cannot alter the environment of the current shell process.

You need to write a function or alias that will operate in your current interactive shell. One of these will work:

```
alias go='cd /really/damn/annoyingly/long/and/it/takes/a/while/to/type'
# or
go() { cd /really/damn/annoyingly/long/and/it/takes/a/while/to/type; }
```

Pick one, save it in your ~/.bashrc, type `source ~/.bashrc` and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

#### Symlink

You could use a symlink, which is a special type of file that links to another file:

```
ln -s "/really/damn/annoyingly/long/and/it/takes/a/while/to/type" link_name
```

This creates a symlink called `link_name` which links to `/really/damn/annoyingly/long/and/it/takes/a/while/to/type`.

Then, in a shell:

```
~$ cd link_name
~/link_name$
```

---

#### Shell variable

Or create a variable:

```
variable_name='/really/damn/annoyingly/long/and/it/takes/a/while/to/type'
```

Put that in your ~/.bashrc, run `source ~/.bashrc`, then you can simply `cd "$variable_name"`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN cd in a script -- just put your `cd` command in a script.  You have to execute it like this though: `. ./script1`.  The `.` in front causes the script to run in your current shell instead of launching a new one.

```
~$ cat script1
cd ./ISO
~$ . ./script1
~/ISO$
```

Comment: Honestly I like Glenn's answer better though, it is a better way to achieve the result.

Comment: `source` is the same as the dot command `.`, and easier to read.